# rpm -ivh, failed dependency already installed

Tags: rpm

I'm having trouble installing a set of custom build rpms.  The spec file produces 7 binary rpms.  I installed 5 of them using rpm -ivh and then decided that I also needed the remaining two.  When I try to install those, rpm complains:

```
# sudo rpm -ivh foo-lib-cpp-devel-0.7.0-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    foo = 0.7.0-1 is needed by foo-lib-cpp-devel-1:0.7.0-1.x86_64
```

Yet that exact dependency is already installed:

```
# rpm -q foo
foo-0.7.0-1.x86_64
```

I discovered 'rpm -R', which provides more details on the package:

```
# rpm -qvRp foo-lib-cpp-devel-0.7.0-1.x86_64.rpm
auto: /usr/bin/pkg-config  
manual: boost-devel  
manual: libevent-devel >= 1.2
auto: libfoo.so.0()(64bit)  
auto: libfootnb.so.0()(64bit)  
auto: libfooz.so.0()(64bit)  
auto: pkgconfig(foo) = 0.7.0
rpmlib: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib: rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
manual: foo = 0.7.0-1
manual: zlib-devel  
rpmlib: rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

The only suspicious thing I see is the '-1:' token in the lib-cpp-devel package, which I can't explain.

What is the '-1:' and could that be related to this issue?  How can I debug this further or workaround it?  FWIW this is all occuring on a relatively fresh install of CentOS 6.

Thanks!

Comment: -1 refers to the rpm release. For example, foo is version 0.7.0, rpm release 1. In the spec file, you'll commonly see it defined like: Release: 1%{?dist}

Comment: It's not the '-1' but the '-1:' (note the colon).  The colon isn't present in the package filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-1:` token is the Epoch tag, so it looks like your RPM may have been built with an Epoch equaling 1. If that's the case, `foo-lib-cpp-devel`'s dependency on `foo` [*must* include the Epoch](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html#S3-RPM-DEPEND-VERSION-NOT-ENOUGH), like so:

```
Requires: foo = 1:0.7.0-1
```

Or, using macros:

```
Requires: foo = %{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely sure that the two packages are compatible, you could do one of the following:

1. Remove the current foo-lib-cpp-devel package using the --nodeps switch on rpm.

1a. Install the new foo-lib-cpp-devel package using rpm (may have to use --nodeps or --force switches)

```
OR
```

2. Install the new foo-lib-cpp-devel package using the --force --nodeps switches on rpm.